# GWT - Cannot display JSON Object on nextline

Tags: json, gwt, line-breaks, flowpanel

I'm using a String builder to display my data in a FlowPanel( parsed JSON data)  and im trying to display each Object on a new line. I have tried using "\n", "\r\n", etc and still no joy. Any ideas?

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("** TODAYS WEATHER** <br/>");
                    builder.append(jsonArray.get(0).isObject().get("Town").isString().stringValue()).append(" ");
                    builder.append(jsonArray.get(0).isObject().get("Weather").isString().stringValue()).append(",");
                    builder.append("<br/>");
                    label.setText(builder.toString()+ "</br>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use environment new line

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("text {0} more text", Environment.NewLine);
string s = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it i'm still getting an error. "New Line can not be resolved or is not a field". I'm using eclipse, and it does not seem to have the required import for the function?

Comment: try this , System.lineSeparator(). from here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29

Comment: Ah, researched a bit more into it and realised that you cannot implement a new line when using Labels. So i changed it to a TextArea and all is working perfect now. Thank you so much for your time !